# Range proof's Confidential Transaction understanding

Tags: cryptography, confidential-transactions

I've some doubt about Greg Maxwell Confidential transaction and hope someone can help to make it clear.
A commitment using Elliptic Curve math is:

```
                                  P=xG + aH
```

where G,H are public value and x,a are private.

My questions are:

1. `xG` is public or private value?
2. if `xG` is a public value  why an attacker cannot simply  make a brute force attack trying all possible value of `a` checking for the equality with the P value?
3. if `xG` is a private value the CT paper tell: `can be proven to be a commitment to a zero by just signing a hash of the commitment with the commitment as the public` or if if you want to prove `a=1` make `C' = C - 1H`
   and then sign the hash of `C'`. How signing `C` or `C'` can I prove the value and also how can I verify a sign if I dont know `xG`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the overall commitment (*P*) is revealed. *G* and *H* are constants known to everyone. *x* (the blinding factor) and *a* (the value) are secret.

> if xG is a private value the CT paper tell: can be proven to be a commitment to a zero by just signing a hash of the commitment with the commitment as the public or if if you want to prove a=1 make C' = C - 1H and then sign the hash of C'. How signing C or C' can I prove the value and also how can I verify a sign if I dont know xG?

You can only sign with a point if it's a known multiple of *G*. By definition, a signature with private key *k* can be verified with public key *kG*. If *P = xG + aH* with *a* nonzero, it is impossible to find a *k* such that *kG = xG + aH* - that would require knowing the ratio between *G* and *H* (and *H* is constructed in such a way that this ratio is unknown to everyone).

Comment: Thanks! If I've understand .. suppose we 've got a commitment C to 1 (C=xG+H) in a set [0-1]. Then make two commitment:
P0 = C=xG+H and P1= C-1H = xG+H-h=xG.
If I want to use this commitment as sign's public key I can do it only for P1 beacause dont know the logaritm of P0?

Comment: You got it. The DL of P1 (wrt G) is x, but the DL of P0 wrt G is not known (to anyone).